# Why do subpages not load htacess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site is configured to automatically redirect to `https://www`.

However, if I try to access subpages I get a 404 error:

```
https://www.example.com.br/a-necessidade-de-dar-razao-da-fe/
```

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1&busca=$2 [NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an erroneous `RewriteCond` directive that results in your front-controller (`index.php`) only being called when you are accessing the site via HTTP (not HTTPS), so attempting to request a page on HTTPS will naturally result in a 404.

You also have your directives in the wrong order. The HTTP to HTTPS (and canonical www) redirect should come first, however, you are also missing an `OR` flag so it would never redirect `http://www.example.com` to HTTPS.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS and canonical www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1&busca=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

However, the `$2` backreference will always be empty (you are only capturing a single pattern in your regex), so the `busca` URL parameter will always be empty.

This also assumes you are behind an SSL proxy.

Clear your browser cache before testing.